# Regex to match value after second string (Java regex parser)

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
<134>1 2019-01-15T10:55:19.016+01:00 Foo Bar 12345 - [Question=Computer-Name Count="1" Computer-Name="IneedThisPart"]
```

What is the regex needed to extract the part I need "IneedThisPart" (with out quotes)

Java regex parser

Comment: why not just substring based on the second to last quote's index?

Comment: could you please suggest a regex ?

Comment: creating a regex to match that could be hard, doing the substring will be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update according to language**

Using java, you can do:

```
^.+"([^"]+)"
```

You'll find your wanted string in group 1

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of string
  .+        # 1 or more any character
  "         # a quote
  (         # start group 1
    [^"]+   # 1 or more non quote
  )         # end group
  "         # a quote
```

Comment: Thanks for downvote, what's the problem?

Comment: not down voting but its not working for me in the tool I'm using.

Comment: @dross: What language/tool are you using? Add the relevant tag in the question.

Comment: Java regex parser

Comment: @dross: I'm not so good at Java, have a try with: `^.+"([^"]+)"`, the wanted string is in group #1

Comment: works nicely for group 1

Answer (score 1):

To find that specific part in your string, you can use this regex,

```
Computer-Name="([^"]+)"
```

Which will look for `Computer-Name="` text and then start group 1 with `(` and capture any text except a `"` and close the group with `)` and further expecting to see a `"` and find data from group1. This regex will work as long as you have `Computer-Name="IneedThisPart"` data in the input string no matter wherever in whatever order. It will always find your desired string.

Here's Java code for same.

```
String s = "<134>1 2019-01-15T10:55:19.016+01:00 Foo Bar 12345 - [Question=Computer-Name Count=\"1\" Computer-Name=\"IneedThisPart\"]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Computer-Name=\"([^\"]+)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("Didn't match");
}
```

Prints,

```
IneedThisPart
```